# Embed Instagram Post in React Native

Tags: react-native, instagram

I have checked any packages for this. Here is the only one I found: https://github.com/GaborWnuk/react-native-instagram-embed
However, it's no longer work in the current version.

Is there any method to embed instagram post in React Native? Like https://www.instagram.com/p/BzNbnJXBe8m/
is the only way using webview in flatlist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try out: 
https://github.com/Kobidl/react-native-embed-instagram
It's working